# what formula is needed to count two specific cells that already include a formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Afternoon all,

I am trying to create an enquiry managment spreadsheet that records all incoming enquires and what has been done to date.

I am trying to get a cell to count how many "New" enquiries David has.

Daivds name is populated via a drop down list and the number of enquiries is counted via the text "NEW" selected from a drop down list.

The formula as I understand it should be along the lines of

```
 =COUNTIF(Enquiries!E4:E309,"NEW")=IF(Enquiries!B4:B309,"DAVID")
```

But i cannot for the life of me get it to work!!

[image: Snippet of spreadsheet]

Comment: `=COUNTIFS(Enquiries!E4:E309,"NEW",Enquiries!B4:B309,"DAVID")`

Answer (score 1):

You should use the formula COUNTIFS() which allows to place more than one condition to do the count. As mentioned in the comments by BigBen, the formula should be as follows:

```
=COUNTIFS(Enquiries!E4:E309,"NEW",Enquiries!B4:B309,"DAVID")
```

If you want to use the formula for different people, which i guess you want, you can change "DAVID" for cell E$2, and block the cells by using `$` symbol, so the formula would be like:

```
=COUNTIFS(Enquiries!$E$4:$E$309,"NEW",Enquiries!$B$4:$B$309,E$2)
```

and then drag the formula horizontally.

You can find more help about the formula on this [link](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/countifs-function-dda3dc6e-f74e-4aee-88bc-aa8c2a866842)